# The night/theme.xml in android studio

Tags: android

The "colorprimary"  changes in `themes.xml` then the button colour also changes "(image in lite mode)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhm0K.jpg) (image in dark mode)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBDpZ.jpg)edittext hint selection colour also changes . I want to edit text colour with out changing the theme and without changing button  colour

Answer (score 0):

I think, is important to mention first that a theme is different than a style. Basically, when you apply a **style** it only affects to the component( edit text, view, textview, etc). But when you apply a **theme** it affects in general terms to the app. More info about in this [Link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-styling-themes-vs-styles-ebe05f917578).

So, if you are applying a **theme** probably you are modifying some attributes that are being used in the app scope such as `primaryColor`, `secondaryColor`, etc. Probably, the editText is using primaryColor in order to set the color of the hint and when you change to another theme, primaryColor is affected, then the color hint of the editText is affected as well.

Based on the above description, we can apply multiple solutions. I would like to suggest the following.

default `theme.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/gray_medium_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/gray_dark</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/cyan</item>

    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditTextStyle</item>

</style>
```

nigh theme `theme.xml`

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>
    </style>
```

`style.xml`

```
<style name="CustomEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gray_normal_light</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_condensed</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textVisiblePassword</item>
</style>
```

Explanation: Another important point about `style` and `themes` is that we can apply something similar to inheritance. It means that we ca re-use some attributes or/and modify others.

So, `<item name="editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditTextStyle</item>` means that for all the edittext on my application I want to set up `CustomEditTextStyle` style. Also, in nigh theme we are applying parent as `parent="AppTheme.Base"` and this parent also has `CustomEditTextStyle` as style for edittext, so it will no change.